# Scholarship effects on later applications

Tags: graduate-school, career-path, funding

I have the choice to either apply for a sholarship or get a regular salary. Economically, the position is slightly favorable (mainly due to pension prospects), but I also want to consider secondary effects such as prestige in the CV w.r.t. lateron applications.

I know it's hard to put a value on such a thing, so I'm interested in your opinions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your situation describes a situation that is relatively common here in Germany, with the choice between "fellowships" at *Gradiuerterkollegen* and traditional degree programs within faculties and departments. If this is in fact your case, I don't think I would make too much of a difference between the statuses—they are both graduate degree programs, and would effectively carry the same weight. It's largely viewed (correctly) as just different means of internally financing graduate studies. Thus, it would not really make a big difference on your later career.

What *can* make a difference, however, are the *duties* assigned to the different programs. Scholarship students may have a substantially reduced set of responsibilities, particularly with respect to teaching and other non-research activities. This may mean that you finish your degree program more quickly and efficiently than someone who has to do substantial teaching as part of the standard graduate program.

Comment: @Neuneck You might want to consider talking to people in the department who have either and check whether it is actually the case - while technically your mentor is not allowed to ask you to do duties others are paid for when you have a scholarship, your department _may_ be understaffed and you might then feel obliged to help anyway...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Thank you for the advice. I'm lucky to be free of teaching duties in both cases. I will choose the faculty position since I do not improve my retirement prospects. These are even larger than I thought at first.